# Listview Source with a foreign key column (WPF MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I have 2 `ObservableCollections` (`Employees` --> FirstName, LastName, DepartmentFK / `Departments` --> Id, Department). `Employees` contains a foreign key (`DepartmentFK`) which is linked to `Id` (`departments` table) on my database tables.

What I want is to display all employees including the department name (instead of the foreign key integer)

My XAML looks like this:

```
<ListView Name="Employees_Listview" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding YourSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="109">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="FirstName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="LastName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Departments" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DepartmentFK}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

So the source for my listview is the `Employees` OC. As I have both collections in my viewmodel, I hope there is an easy way to achieve this.

Can anyone show me how to do this?

Comment: You shouldn't let your `View` do the `ViewModel` work. You should create a custom class to hold results you want to show and do the filtering in your `VM`.

Comment: The custom class Sach refers to might be an Employee viewmodel that has all of Employee's properties, plus a Department property that's a reference to a department object. Then you can bind to `Department.Name` instead of `DepartmentFK`.

Comment: I do have a employee viewmodel with all the properties like LastName, etc. and even with the department name but my source is the ObservableCollection "Employees" and this one just have the foreign key. So I have to create a new collection with Department.Name instead of the foreign key? (sorry for this probably "stupid" question but C#, WPF and MVVM is brand new for me)

Comment: @Moritz Your `EmployeeViewModel` in your `Employees` collection should have a `Department` property that is a reference to a `Department` object. I have no idea what "create a new collection with Department.Name" means.

Comment: @Ed Tried the approach Sach posted yesterday and it seems to work, although I have changed everything to an ObservableCollection. Gonna read a few more posts, there has to be a way without a third class (DisplayEmployees)

Comment: oh my gosh .... took me more than 20 hours to understand your approach -.- I added a new property to my EmployeeEntity so I can use my original "Employees" ObservableCollection (just have to exclude this property from beeing send to my update because there is no such table). 
    [Computed]
    public DepartmentEntity Dept
    {
    get
    {
    var container = ContainerConfig.Configure();
    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
    var test = scope.Resolve<IDepartmentRepository>();
    dept = test.GetById(DepartmentFK);
    }
    return dept;
    }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your `Employee` and `Department` classes are like so:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentFK { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Dept { get; set; }
}
```

Then I'd create a new 'display' class that will hold results you want to display, namely `FirstName`, `LastName`, and an object of `Department` class:

```
public class DisplayEmployee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Department Dept { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you can filter your `Employee` data in your `ViewModel` and create a list of `DisplayEmployee`:

```
Employees = new List<Employee>
{
    new Employee() { FirstName = "A", LastName = "Z", DepartmentFK = "D1" },
    new Employee() { FirstName = "B", LastName = "Y", DepartmentFK = "D2" },
    new Employee() { FirstName = "C", LastName = "X", DepartmentFK = "D1" },
    new Employee() { FirstName = "D", LastName = "W", DepartmentFK = "D3" },
    new Employee() { FirstName = "E", LastName = "V", DepartmentFK = "D2" }
};

Departments = new List<Department>
{
    new Department() { ID = "D1", Dept = "Department 01" },
    new Department() { ID = "D2", Dept = "Department 02" },
    new Department() { ID = "D3", Dept = "Department 03" },
    new Department() { ID = "D4", Dept = "Department 04" }
};

DisplayEmployees = new List<DisplayEmployee>();
foreach (var emp in Employees)
{
    DisplayEmployees.Add(
    new DisplayEmployee()
    {
        FirstName = emp.FirstName,
        LastName = emp.LastName,
        Dept = Departments.Where(x => x.ID == emp.DepartmentFK).FirstOrDefault()
    });
}
```

Now in your `XAML`:

```
<ListView Name="Employees_Listview" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayEmployees, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding YourSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="109">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="FirstName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="LastName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Departments" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Dept.Dept}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

---

### Edit

You can even make the `DisplayEmployee` a derived class of `Employee`:

```
public class DisplayEmployee : Employee
{
    public Department Dept { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sach, are you here. I need help